# Pasar campos delimitados por comas a varias filas access 2013

Tags: vba, ms-access

Buen dia a todos el problema que tengo es una tabla con la siguiente info

```
COMPANY  PRODUCTS
AAA      A,B,C
BBB      A,C,D,F
CCC      D
DDD      F,G,H,I,J,K,L
```

y yo quisiera ver si se puede guardar con algun codigo de la siguiente forma:

```
COMPANY  PRODUCTS
AAA      A
AAA      B
AAA      C
BBB      A
BBB      C
ETC.
```

si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradeceria mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui te comparto un script que te puede dar una idea de cómo hacerlo.

La idea es iterar la tabla en donde tienes los valores separados por coma, en cada ciclo, a su véz iteras los valores separados por coma con split y lo insertas en donde necesitas. Aplicando este ejemplo con seguridad lo solucionas.

```
dim strColors() as string
dim ID as integer
dim rs as dao.recordset
dim i as integer
dim strSql as string
set rs = currentdb.openrecordset("yourTableName")
do while not rs.eof
  ID = rs!ID
  strColors = split(rs!colors, ",")
  for i = lbound(colors) to ubound(colors)
    strSql = "Insert into yourNewTable (ID, Colors) values (" & ID & ", '" & colors(i) & "')"
    currentdb.execute strSql 
  next i
  rs.moveNext
loop
```

Saludos,

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda me fue muy util

Answer (score 1):

Gracias Jorge Londoño el codigo me quedo de la siguiente forma por si a alguien le sirve.

```
Public Function FieldtoLinePro()
    Dim strProductos() As String
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim rs As dao.Recordset
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strSql As String
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("COMPANY-T")
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        ID = rs!ID
        strProductos = Split(rs!PRODUCTS, ",")
        For i = LBound(strProductos) To UBound(strProductos)
            strSql = "INSERT INTO [PRODUCTS-N] (C_ID,PRODUCTS) VALUES (" & ID & ",'" & strProductos(i) & "');"
            CurrentDb.Execute strSql
        Next i
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    FieldtoLinePro = True
End Function
```